reCAPTCHA v3: Low Scores for Valid Users and High Scores for Spammers
I’m currently facing challenges with my reCAPTCHA v3 implementation, and I’m looking for guidance on how to resolve them.
Setup

When a user clicks the Submit button, the frontend renders an HTML
page with a hidden reCAPTCHA v3 widget.
The widget generates a token tied to an action (e.g., submit_form).
This token is auto-submitted to the backend API for validation.

Backend Logic
The backend validates the token by calling the https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify endpoint.
I check the following:

success is true.
The score is above a threshold (e.g., 0.5).

Issues

Valid Users with Low Scores:
Many legitimate users are now receiving scores between 0 and 0.3.
Spammers with High Scores:
Bots and spammers are consistently scoring between 0.7 and 0.9.
remoteip Impact: Including the remoteip parameter during verification hasn’t shown any noticeable improvement.

What I’ve Tried

Sending the user's remoteip for reCAPTCHA verification.
Dynamically adjusting the score threshold based on the action (e.g., stricter
thresholds for signup compared to login).
Implementing rate-limiting based on IP, though this hasn’t helped as spammers are using a wide range of IP addresses.

Questions

What could be causing valid users to receive such low scores?
Why are spammers receiving high scores, and how can I address this?
Are there additional validation mechanisms or best practices I can
apply to improve this setup?
How can I supplement reCAPTCHA v3 to better differentiate between
legitimate users and spammers?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
